# Will Flash Popularity Become AIR Popularity?

Tags: user-interface, cross-platform, air, desktop

[This is a community Wiki so do **not** bother voting it down if it seems like a poll question. It is.]

Will Adobe be able to translate its success in Flash Penetration (although also questionable, see my post [here](http://compileyouidontevenknowyou.blogspot.com/2008/01/flash-penetration-and-bullshit.html)) to Adobe AIR? Is Adobe AIR the "next big thing" in a desktop platform, just another player (along with what else?), or will it die a silent and unimportant death?

Comment: The bigger question is "Will people ever quit abusing the community wiki feature"?  :-)

Comment: Or the comments, which are totally unvotable in all cases :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, until they sort out, at the least, the following issue:

When you visit a site that needs Flash and you haven't got Flash installed, you get a very standard looking popup asking you if you to install it, and mentioning in the notes that it may not be safe to install an untrusted plugin.

When you visit a site that lets you download an AIR app, it pops up big red screaming warnings about the imminent trashing of your computer, the theft of your identity and a life of torment[1]. Unless, of course, all the bedroom programmers decide to cough up the *ongoing* cost of certification.

User encouragement FAIL. Hobby developer encouragement FAIL. Technophobe terrorficiation avoidance FAIL.

I love AIR, but I don't know what they were thinking with the installer. Laywers' office moved closer to the developers' over at HQ or something?

[1]Actual message may vary.

Comment: This is very true. I would say, "Adobe will get over it" but I've read some conversations with Adobe AIR evangelists and they don't even BEGIN to understand how they're jeopardizing the future of AIR with their legalistic crap (including the distribution of the AIR installer itself)... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer **NO**

It's not fair to compare Flash's web success with Desktop or obvious reasons.

Flash developers were already using flash to develop desktop applications and now they've got a better framework. It'll be used by so many people but I don't it ever will be that popular.

Comment: That's interesting and perhaps true, but why? Without the why it's not really an answer...

Comment: I mean what's the point other than it's just a shiny framework. Why would I wanna install another crappy framework like Java or AIR, or yet-another-shiny-runtime to my system to have some more apps....

Comment: AIR is good but it doesn't provide any extra other than AS guys can develop desktop applications now. Or your old flash apps can run in in desktop easier way. However this is not an advantage for users this is an advantage for developers.

Comment: If you are aiming for desktop without a legacy flash application why would you develop your application in AIR? I can't see a good reason, also now you are limited with lots of sandbox issues + Action Script.

Comment: Stupid character limitation :)

Comment: Slough: If it's not much help to you, fair enough, but to someone who knows nothing about desktop apps and a few things about flash and/or javascript it's a minor miracle. It's lowering the bar for creating a desktop app, which means more apps for a user.

Comment: "which means more apps for a user" -- but by admitting to lowering the bar, we're admitting that this will introduce even MORE bad programming into the wilde. One must qualify "more apps" with "badly designed and/or implemented".

Answer (score 1):

I think that AIR will be around for a long time, it is great for web geeks who want desktop versions of the web applications.

I doubt that it will ever reach mainstream appeal, the masses need flash to watch their funny YouTube videos, but they'll never think to get AIR in order to use TweetDeck. The desktop apps they use are the ones that are already installed on their machine.

Comment: Interesting. Part of the question comes after having seen, for instance, eBay Desktop. Does it help that some bigger companies are betting on AIR?

Answer (score 1):

If AIR has improved incorporation of HTML content, it will be very successful.
If the ability to render HTML content has not been improved, then my humble opinion is that it will be mixed.

Comment: I don't get it - you write HTML for webkit (no cross-browser hassles, yay; nice CSS extras, yay; it's not IE, yay) and press a couple of buttons. What's to improve?

Answer (score 0):

No.
The competition on desktop application market is much bigger, and users are expectiong more functionality and performance from desktop application than from web application, and AIR is just not there yet wrt performance and desktop capabilities.

Comment: What´s the competition, for cross-platform dev?